# Jquery Treeview items with format tag

Tags: jquery, tags, treeview

My jquery treeview works fine but when I add the some tags such as bold **Title**  to the part of item lines, it does not work when I click that part. Only the untagged part can be clicked. Is there any other way I can click the whole item with different formatted parts? Thanks.

Here is the code. when click MYITEM, no response. but when I click Item or contents, it works.

```
<ul id="black" class="treeview-black">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>
        <span>Item <b>MYITEM</b> contents </span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>Item 2.1</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 2.1.1</li>
                    <li>Item 2.1.2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Item 2.2</li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

       $("#black").treeview({
        collapsed: true,
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please give us some code and/or a jfiddle of your code - otherwise, we can't help you!

Comment: Code added. Thanks, LordT.